# Angular 14 with Module Federation library not working if one remote is not available

Tags: angular, angular-module-federation

We have an Angular project with multiple micro-frontends using Manfred Steyer's module federation library.

After migrating from module federation v12 to v14, the application stops working if one remote endpoint is unavailable. In contrast, with the old version, the application kept working except the not available micro-frontends.

Our webpack config file for the shell part:

```
const { share, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'shell',
  filename: 'shell.js',

  sharedMappings: ['frontend/mfe-shared'],

  exposes: {
    './Module': 'apps/shell/src/app/app.module.ts',
  },
  remotes: {
    dashboard: `http://localhost:4201/dashboard.js`,
    offers: `http://localhost:4206/offers.js`,
    clients: `http://localhost:4206/clients.js`,
  },    
  shared: share({
    '@angular/core': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '14.2.12' },
    '@angular/common': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '14.2.12' },
    '@angular/common/http': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '14.2.12' },
    '@angular/router': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '14.2.12' },
    'ngx-webstorage-service': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true },
  }),
});
```

The webpack config file for the `dashboard` remote, for instance:

```
const { share, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'dashboard',
  filename: 'dashboard.js',

  sharedMappings: ['frontend/mfe-shared'],
  exposes: {
    './Module': 'apps/dashboard/src/app/app.module.ts',
  },

  shared: share({
    '@angular/core': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '14.2.12' },
    '@angular/common': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '14.2.12' },
    '@angular/common/http': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '14.2.12' },
    '@angular/router': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '14.2.12' },
    'ngx-webstorage-service': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true },
  }),
});
```

Our routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('dashboard/Module').then(({ AppModule }) => AppModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'client',
    loadChildren: () => import('partner/Module').then(({ AppModule }) => AppModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'offers',
    loadChildren: () => import('iam/Module').then(({ IamModule }) => IamModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy', paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always' }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

With the current configuration, if the `dashboard` remote is not available, the whole application displays only a blank page, even if all remote modules, but `dashboard`, have been downloaded. Is anything missing in the new configuration? Aside from this aspect, the application works fine, if all remotes are available.

Our versions:

- Angular 14.2.12
- @angular-architects/module-federation: 14.3.14

Comment: could you try replacing `import('dashboard/Module')` with `loadRemoteModule({type: 'script', remoteName: 'dashboard', exposedModule: './Module'})`?

Comment: Hi @Andrei, I already solved it a couple of weeks ago using indeed the loadRemoteModule. I added as answer my solution in case it might help others as well. Thanks for reminding me to add the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `loadRemoteModule` and moving all remotes there allowed preventing the app to stop working if a single micro frontend was not responding.

Our shell routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule(getConfig('dashboard')).then((m) => m.AppModule),
  },
// ....
```

Our `webpack.config.js` for the shell:

```
module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'shell',
  filename: 'shell.js',

  exposes: {
    './Module': 'apps/shell/src/app/app.module.ts',
  },
  remotes: {
    // Remotes are loaded as remote module in shell/app.routing file
  },
 // ...
```